# Buildozer failed -- Python+Kivy to Android apk

Tags: python, android, github, kivy, buildozer

I've been having trouble creating an APK with Buildozer for days now.
Since this is my first app, I don't have any experience here yet.

In the meantime I try to do this via Github. Unfortunately I still get an error here and can't solve the problem.
I would also nciht be surprised if I have already built more errors, in my search for a solution.

I hope someone of you can help me here or nudge me in the right direction.
Meanwhile, I have already reached the phase where only blindly tried and hoped by chance to find the solution.

my current buildozer.spec version

```
[app]
title = Paletten
package.name = com.example.paletten
version = 1.0
android.permissions = INTERNET
requirements = python3,gspread,oauth2client,kivy,kivymd
source.dir = .
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,json
source.exclude_exts = spec,txt
source.exclude_dirs = tests,__pycache__
icon.filename = Signatur.jpg
entry.point = main.py
android.archs = arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a


[buildozer]
log_level = 2
warn_on_root = 1
```

github workflow

```
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # used to cache dependencies with a timeout
      - name: Get Date
        id: get-date
        run: |
          echo "::set-output name=date::$(/bin/date -u "+%Y%m%d")"
        shell: bash

      - name: Cache Buildozer global directory
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: .buildozer_global
          key: buildozer-global-${{ hashFiles('buildozer.spec') }} # Replace with your path

      - uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: .buildozer
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ steps.get-date.outputs.date }}-${{ hashFiles('buildozer.spec') }}

      - name: Build with Buildozer
        uses: ArtemSBulgakov/buildozer-action@v1
        id: buildozer
        with:
          command: buildozer android debug
          buildozer_version: master

      - name: Upload artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: package
          path: ${{ steps.buildozer.outputs.filename }}
```

the current error:

```
[WARNING]: ERROR: /github/workspace/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 failed!
Command failed: ('/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=com.example.paletten', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,gspread,oauth2client,kivy,kivymd', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/github/workspace/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug')
Error code: 1
```

If someone has time and desire to help me here I would be very happy.
I have been working with Python for only 4 months and am therefore unfortunately still a beginner.